# jQuery + Regex: How to change "$1.23 " to " 1.23%"?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have text in my select options that I want to replace when a user clicks on a certain part of the form. I want all occurrences of `$...` to be replaced with `...%` and vice versa like so:

```
    $("#coupon_type option").on("click", function(){
        var coupon_type = $(this).val();
        if (coupon_type == 'FreeShippingCoupon') {
            $(".coupon_value_div").hide();
        } else if (coupon_type == 'PercentageCoupon') {
            //replace all the '$ ...' with '... %'
            //for text in $("#coupon_value option").text()
            $(".coupon_value_div").show();
        } else if (coupon_type == 'FlatCoupon') {
            //replace all the '... %' with '$ ...'
            $(".coupon_value_div").show();
        }
    });
```

I want to replace the text in this select:

```
    <select id="coupon_value" name="coupon[value]">
        <option value="5">$5.00</option>
        <option value="10">$10.00</option>
        <option value="15">$15.00</option>
        <option value="20">$20.00</option>
        <option value="25">$25.00</option>
        <option value="30">$30.00</option>
        <option value="35">$35.00</option>
        <option value="40">$40.00</option>
        <option value="45">$45.00</option>
        <option value="50">$50.00</option>
        <option value="55">$55.00</option>
        <option value="60">$60.00</option>
        <option value="65">$65.00</option>
        <option value="70">$70.00</option>
        <option value="75">$75.00</option>
        <option value="80">$80.00</option>
        <option value="85">$85.00</option>
        <option value="90">$90.00</option>
        <option value="95">$95.00</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is relevant to the actual problem. The actual problem just need an input of string containing both `$...` and `...%`, then you may provide some code you tried to convert the input into the desired result.

Comment: Maybe my update makes it clearer?

Comment: you want to change the text when click where?

Comment: @LGVentura inside the first block of code that I pasted. `$("#coupon_type option").on("click", function(){...}` that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `text` method to transform the values in the options, and a regular expression to only do the replacement if the text is the expected:

```
$('#coupon_value option').text(function(i, s){ return s.replace(/^\$(.+)$/, '$1%'); });
```

And the other way around:

```
$('#coupon_value option').text(function(i, s){ return s.replace(/^(.+)%$/, '$$$1'); });
```

Comment: Thanks @Guffa. Could you explain why you need 3 `$$$` in the last line?

Comment: @Edmund: The first two is to insert a `$` in the result, the `$1` is to insert the matched group from the search, i.e. the value.

Comment: @Edmund: Exactly. You can see the options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: Just so I understand, would this switch the formattings if they happen together on one line? (For instance `5.1% , $2.0` => `$5.1 , 2.0%` ) Or would it overwrite the $ format to a % format, then switch them both back to $: `$5.1 , $2.0`?

Comment: @zx81: This will only change the text if it matches the expression, so `5.1% , $2.0` would never be changed, but `$5.1 , 2.0%` would be changed by the first one to `5.1 , 2.0%%` (and back by the second). The solution is just for changing the values in the options just as they are in the question, it's not a solution for changing values in an arbitrary string.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks for explaining... You understood the requirements better than I did—in my own answer I did a three-step replacement to avoid the overwrite problem. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

With a three-step dance:

```
step1 = string.replace(/\$([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/g, "DOLLAR$1");
step2 = step1.replace(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)%/g, "$$$1");
step3 = step2.replace(/DOLLAR([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/g, "$1%");
```

**Explanation**

To operate the switch-a-roo,

1. The first one changes your `$1.23` to `DOLLAR1.23`
2. The second one changes your `1.23%` to `$1.23` (the many `$` in the replacement are because you need a `$` to escape a literal `$`)
3. The third one changes your `DOLLAR1.23` to `1.23%`

Comment: and the other clause?

Comment: @scrowler I had missed that. You're a few hours' drive a way, is that why your comment was so fast? Cheers, mate! :)